# R:dplyr: How to make percentage column based on factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

**I need to transform the data with dplyr in order to do some plotting**

I need to make a new column that says what is the percentage of a row based on the factor it belongs to.

Basically I need to do this plot with percentages, so all columns would be the same hight, showing the percentage of every tv brand by price range.

At the end I want to achieve this (based on my data):

[image]

From this:

[image]

Step 1:

Group by "rangos", "marca". Then create a new colum "cantidad.marca" with the length of the brands in each price range.

Finally, I wanted to make a column "percentage" that would calculate the total number of ocurrenses by "range (rango)" and divide each "brand" in that range to that numbers.

I have used this code, and also this variation `porcentaje = cantidad.marca/sum(s.tvs.porcentajes$cantidad.marca)`

```
s.tvs.porcentajes <- s.tvs %>%
                        group_by(rangos, marca) %>%
                        summarise(cantidad.marca = length(marca),
                                  porcentaje = cantidad.marca/sum(cantidad.marca))
```

Another approach:

I wanted to know the total number of tv brands in each range and use those numbers to divide the occurences in the other data frame.

```
s.tvs.p <- s.tvs %>%
        group_by(rangos) %>%
        summarise(totales.rango = length(rangos))
```

But I don't know how to combine those.

Any hint?

This is `s.tvs`:
You can reproduce it with this code:

```
s.tvs <- structure(list(marca = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("LG", 
"SAMSUNG", "SONY", "HISENSE", "PANASONIC", "AOC"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), producto = c("LED 55\" XBR-55X855B", "LED 65\" 65JU7500", 
"LED 49\" XBR-49X855B", "LED 55\" 55JS9000", "LED 65\" 65JS9000", 
"LED 32\" 32LF595B", "LED 32\"  TC-32AS600L", "LED 79\" 79UG8800", 
"LED 48\" 48JU6700 ULT...", "LED 49\" 49LF5900 WEB...", "LED 55\" 55LF6500", 
"LED 42\" TC-42AS610L", "LED 40\" 40J5500", "LED 49\" 49LF6350", 
"LED 65\" XBR-65X855C", "LED 50\" KDL-50FA95C", "LED 79\" 79UG8800", 
"LED 55\" KDL55W805C", "LED 49\" 49LF6350", "LED 49\" ULTRA HD 4K ...", 
"LED 84\"  84UB9800", "LED 55\" KDL-55W805B", "LED 55\" 55LF6350", 
"LED 65\" KDL65W855C", "LED 50\" KDL-50W805B", "LED 48\" 48J5500", 
"LED 65\" 65UG8700  WE...", "LED 50\" KDL50W805C", "LED 55\" JU6700", 
"LED 50\" SMART ULTRA ...", "LED 50\" KDL50W805C", "LED 55\" JU6700", 
"LED 55\" 55UG8700 WEB...", "LED 55\" XBR-55X855C", "LED 48\" LTDN48K390XW...", 
"LED 50\" 50J5500", "LED 48\" 48J5500", "LED 55\" KDL55W805C", 
"LED 55\"  55LB7200", "LED 60\"  60LB5800", "LED 65\" XBR-65X855C", 
"LED 60\" 60JU6500 + H...", "LED 50\" KDL-50FA95C", "LED 60\" KDL-60W605", 
"LED 40\" 40J5300", "LED 49\" 49UF8500", "LED 40\" 40J5500", 
"LED 40\" 40J6400", "LED 55\" KDL-55W805B", "LED 49\" 49LF6400", 
"LED 55\" XBR-55X905C", "LED 40\" LEDN40K360PV...", "LED 65\" 65UG8700  WE...", 
"LED 48\" 48J5300", "LED 50\" KDL50W805C", "LED 55\" 55UG8700 WEB...", 
"LED 75\" XBR-75X945C", "LED 49\" 49LF5900 WEB...", "LED 65\" 65UF8500", 
"LED 40\" UN40J6500 SM...", "LED 49\" 49LF5900 WEBOS LITE", "LED 40\" UN40J6500 SMART TV", 
"LED 55\" 55UF9500", "LED 49\" 49LF6350", "LED 32\" HD 2HDMI 2US...", 
"LED 65\" 65JU7500", "LED 65\" XBR-65X905C", "LED 32\" 32J4000", 
"LED 70\" ULTRA HD 4K ...", "LED 50\" KDL-50FA95C", "SMART TV 50\" UN50JS7...", 
"LED 55\" 55UF8500", "LED 55\" 55J6500", "LED 48\" 48J5500", 
"LED 48\" KDL-48R555C", "LED 40\" KDL-40R354B", "LED 60\" KDL-60W605", 
"LED 48\" LTDN48K20DAM", "LED 55\" 55JU6500", "LED 55\" XBR-55X855C", 
"LED 43\" 43LF6350", "LED 49\" 49LF6450", "LED 55\" 55UF6800 WEB...", 
"LED 32\"  TC-32AS600L", "OLED 55\" 55EC9300", "LED 65\" 65UF9500", 
"LED 55\" XBR-55X855B", "LED 40\" FULL HD 40D5...", "LED 48\" UN48J6400", 
"LED 40\" LE40F1551 FU...", "LED 32\" 32J4300", "LED 49\" LF5400", 
"LED 49\" XBR-49X855B", "LED 55\" ULTRA HD 4K ...", "LED 32\" KDL-32R304B", 
"LED 55\" KDL55W805C", "SMART TV 55\" UN55JS7...", "LED 32\" 32LF595B", 
"LED 48\" 48JU6700", "LED 32\" JH4005", "LED 40\" TC-L40SV7L", 
"LED 65\" KDL65W855C", "LED 55\" 55LF6350", "LED 50\" 50JU6500", 
"LED 48\" 48J6500", "LED 40\" KDL-40R555C", "LED 32\" KDL-32R505C", 
"LED 49\" 49UF6400", "LED 43\" 43UF6750", "LED 55\" SMART FULL H...", 
"LED 58\" LE58F1552 FU...", "LED 84\"  84UB9800", "LED 48\" LTDN48K390XW...", 
"LED 49\" XBR-49X835C", "LED 48\" 48JU6700 ULT...", "LED 32\" LE32W454F", 
"LED 50\" KDL-50W805B", "LED 43\" 43UF6400", "LED 58\" 58UF8300 WEB...", 
"LED 32\" SMART HD 32K...", "LED 43\" HD 43LF5410", "LED 42\" TC-42AS610L", 
"LED 70\" KDL-70W855B", "LED 40\" SMART FULL H...", "LED 79\" 79UG8800", 
"LED 32\" 32LF585B", "LED 48\" UN48JU6000", "LED 50\" SMART ULTRA ...", 
"LED 32\" 32LF550B", "LED 32\" TC-32A400L", "LED 55\" 55J5500  ", 
"LED 48\" 48JU6700", "LED 55\" 55J6500", "OLED 55\" 55EC9300", 
"LED 65\" 65JU7500", "LED 48\" 48JU6700 ULT...", "LED 55\" 55UF6800 WEB...", 
"LED 49\" XBR-49X855B", "LED 65\" XBR-65X905C", "LED 43\" 43UF6750", 
"LED 84\"  84UB9800", "LED 55\" XBR-55X905C", "LED 58\" 58UF8300 WEB...", 
"LED 79\" 79UG8800", "LED 55\" XBR-55X855B", "LED 65\" 65JU7500", 
"LED 48\" 48JU6700", "LED 55\" XBR-55X855C", "LED 75\" XBR-75X945C", 
"LED 48\" UN48JU6000"), precio.nuevo = c(4999L, 9199L, 3999L, 
7999L, 11999L, 1299L, 1199L, 16999L, 2999L, 1699L, 3399L, 1899L, 
1599L, 2099L, 8999L, 3999L, 19599L, 4299L, 1899L, 2899L, 17999L, 
3499L, 2499L, 5999L, 2699L, 2199L, 8999L, 3499L, 3999L, 2599L, 
3499L, 4499L, 5999L, 5999L, 1899L, 1999L, 1999L, 4299L, 3599L, 
3499L, 8999L, 5999L, 4299L, 3699L, 1399L, 2999L, 1399L, 1699L, 
3299L, 2599L, 7999L, 849L, 6999L, 1799L, 3499L, 5499L, 23999L, 
1599L, 7399L, 1599L, 1599L, 1599L, 4549L, 1699L, 799L, 9199L, 
11999L, 899L, 8499L, 3999L, 4599L, 3799L, 3999L, 1799L, 2199L, 
1299L, 3699L, 1199L, 3499L, 5999L, 1399L, 2499L, 3999L, 1199L, 
7999L, 6649L, 4999L, 849L, 2299L, 999L, 999L, 1399L, 3999L, 3699L, 
949L, 4299L, 5699L, 1299L, 2999L, 899L, 1499L, 5999L, 2499L, 
2799L, 2999L, 1599L, 1199L, 2399L, 1699L, 2499L, 2399L, 19999L, 
1399L, 3999L, 2849L, 799L, 2699L, 1899L, 4499L, 999L, 1399L, 
1899L, 6499L, 1099L, 15999L, 999L, 2599L, 2249L, 899L, 899L, 
3299L, 2999L, 3999L, 7999L, 9199L, 2849L, 3999L, 3999L, 11999L, 
1699L, 19999L, 7999L, 4499L, 15999L, 4999L, 9199L, 2999L, 5999L, 
23999L, 2599L), categoria = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
), .Label = c("SMART TV", "TODO LED", "TV-LED-CURVO", "ULTRA-HD-4K"
), class = "factor"), rangos = structure(c(5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
3L), .Label = c("ENTRE S/.500 Y S/.1500", "ENTRE S/.1500 Y S/.2500", 
"ENTRE S/.2500 Y S/.3500", "ENTRE S/.3500 Y S/.4500", "MAYOR A S/.4,500"
), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), .Names = c("marca", "producto", 
"precio.nuevo", "categoria", "rangos"), row.names = c(NA, 150L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Edited akrun, thanks for notifiying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part of your question you can get the percentage column (porcentaje) with this.

```
library(dplyr) 
s.tvs.porcentajes <- s.tvs %>%
  group_by(rangos, marca) %>%
  summarise(cantidad.marca = length(marca)) %>% 
           mutate( porcentaje = cantidad.marca/sum(cantidad.marca))
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [22 x 4]
Groups: rangos [5]

                    rangos     marca cantidad.marca porcentaje
                    (fctr)    (fctr)          (int)      (dbl)
1   ENTRE S/.500 Y S/.1500        LG              7 0.25000000
2   ENTRE S/.500 Y S/.1500   SAMSUNG              5 0.17857143
3   ENTRE S/.500 Y S/.1500      SONY              3 0.10714286
4   ENTRE S/.500 Y S/.1500   HISENSE              7 0.25000000
5   ENTRE S/.500 Y S/.1500 PANASONIC              4 0.14285714
6   ENTRE S/.500 Y S/.1500       AOC              2 0.07142857
7  ENTRE S/.1500 Y S/.2500        LG             13 0.41935484
8  ENTRE S/.1500 Y S/.2500   SAMSUNG             10 0.32258065
9  ENTRE S/.1500 Y S/.2500      SONY              2 0.06451613
10 ENTRE S/.1500 Y S/.2500   HISENSE              3 0.09677419
..                     ...       ...            ...        ...
```

To plot the chart:

```
library(ggplot2)
plt <- ggplot(s.tvs.porcentajes, aes(x=rangos, y= porcentaje ,fill=marca)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .7)
```

[image]

If you want percentages in the y-axis:

```
library(scales)
plt + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

[image]

Comment: I needed mutate also. Thanks very much for your complete answer.

Comment: how to make the y axis to show: 100% instead of 1.00? and so on with all the values? thanks!

Comment: @OmarGonzales I edited my answer to show percentages in the y-axis

Answer (score 1):

```
library(rCharts)
n1 <- nPlot(porcentaje ~ rangos, group = marca, data= s.tvs.porcentajes, type = 'multiBarChart')
 n1
n1$save("tvbrand.html")  # saving as html page
n1$publish("NCR", host = 'gist') #posting on webpage
```

Comment: I get this error with you code: Error in getLayer.formula(...) : object 'marca' not found. After using mpalanco code there is a column "marca", what is happening? Thanks.